# Find a tighter upper bound for the ratio involving quadratic forms

Tags: matrices, inequality, quadratic-forms

For an $M\times M$ matrix

$$\mathbf{R}=\mathbf{I}+\sum_{k=1}^{L}\lambda_k^2\mathbf{a}_k\mathbf{a}_k^H=\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{A}^H$$

where $\mathbf{I}$ is an identity matrix, $\mathbf{\Lambda}$ is a diagonal matrix with real elements $\lambda_k^2\ge1$ and $\mathbf{A}=(\mathbf{a}_1,\mathbf{a}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{a}_L)$ with $\mathbf{a}_k$ being an $M\times1$ column vector whose norm is $\sqrt{M}$.

In addition, the $m$-th ($1\le m\le M$) element of $\mathbf{a}_k$ is given by $e^{j2\pi(m-1)c\sin\theta_k}$,
where $j=\sqrt{-1}$, $\theta_k\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ is an angle and $c$ is a real constant. The value of the $L$ angles are all different, thus $A$ is full column rank.

Let $\mathbf{a}_p$ be the projection of column vector $\mathbf{a}$, which has the same form with $\mathbf{a}_k$ but with a different angle $\theta$, onto the column space of $\mathbf{A}=(\mathbf{a}_1,\mathbf{a}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{a}_L)$.

Given the above background, I want to bound the following ratio

$$r = \dfrac{\mathbf{a}_p^H\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{a}_p-\left(\mathbf{a}_p^H\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{a}_p/||\mathbf{a}_p||\right)^2}{M-||\mathbf{a}_p||^2+\mathbf{a}_p^H\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{a}_p}$$

My first attempt:

$$r = \dfrac{\mathbf{a}_p^H\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{a}_p-\left(\mathbf{a}_p^H\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{a}_p/||\mathbf{a}_p||\right)^2}{M-||\mathbf{a}_p||^2+\mathbf{a}_p^H\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{a}_p}\le \dfrac{\mathbf{a}_p^H\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{a}_p||\mathbf{a}_p||^2}{(M-||\mathbf{a}_p||^2)||\mathbf{a}_p||^2+\mathbf{a}_p^H\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{a}_p||\mathbf{a}_p||^2}$$

Using the eigenvalue decomposition of $\mathbf{R}$, it is easy to verify

$$||\mathbf{a}_p||^2 \ge \mathbf{a}_p^H\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{a}_p$$

Thus,

$$r \le \dfrac{\mathbf{a}_p^H\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{a}_p||\mathbf{a}_p||^2}{(M-||\mathbf{a}_p||^2)||\mathbf{a}_p||^2+\mathbf{a}_p^H\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{a}_p||\mathbf{a}_p||^2} \le  \dfrac{\mathbf{a}_p^H\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{a}_p||\mathbf{a}_p||^2}{(M-||\mathbf{a}_p||^2)\mathbf{a}_p^H\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{a}_p+\mathbf{a}_p^H\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{R}^{-1}\mathbf{a}_p||\mathbf{a}_p||^2}=\dfrac{||\mathbf{a}_p||^2}{M}$$

As a consequence, one upper bound for $r$ is $\dfrac{||\mathbf{a}_p||^2}{M}$.

But through numerical tests, this bound is 10 times larger than the real values of $r$. The following figure is one of the numerical test results. The figure is drawn as a function of $\mathbf{a}$, or more specifically, as a function of $\theta$.

[image]

Can the ratio be tighter bounded?

Thank you.

P.S.,

1.Through simulations, it is found that $r$ decreases as $M$ increases. Can this be explained mathematically?

2.This problems comes from array signal processing.

Comment: Is $A^H$ supposed to be the transpose of $A$?

Comment: @CaptainLama Yes, it is. It's Hermitian transpose.

Comment: Please use `\|` for the norms

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Do you mean changing the $||\cdot||$ to \|?

Comment: That is correct